# Tooltip not working the way it should in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

Following is my fiddle where I am trying to display tooltip on the map tag of an image. The tooltip works fine if I am using firefox but it doesnot work fine on chrome. Kindly take a look at following fiddle and hover over the to edges of an image and you'll see instead of bottom the tooltip is appearing at the top left. Kindly let me know how can I fix it for chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/4HptX/53/

```
    <div class="pull-left">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img width="54" height="17" border="0" style="margin-left:15px;" usemap="#Map" alt="" src="http://www.dscl.org/eTitles/device-apple-mac-button.jpg">
    <map name="Map">
        <area href="#hmm" coords="2,0,21,19" shape="rect" title="" onclick="showsection('qal')" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="grid-menu" data-original-title="Why its not on bottom?">
        <area href="#hmm" coords="36,-1,56,19" shape="rect" title="" onclick="showsection('qa')" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="grid-menu" data-original-title="Questions | Answers">
    </map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that bootstrap is using to determine where to draw the imagemap is returning unexpected results in Chrome for the areas.* Unfortunately, there's no straightforward way to change how it calculates the position for this explicit case.

As such, my initial thought would be to change the way you are applying the tooltips. If instead of just using the tooltip applied to the image map areas, you locate it based on the image, and toggle it based on mouseover/mouseout of the map areas, I think you arrive at the desired results.

Instead of

```
$('.grid-menu').tooltip();
```

Try

```
$('.grid-menu').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('#myImg').tooltip({placement: 'bottom', title: $(this).data('original-title')});
    $('#myImg').tooltip('show');
}).on('mouseout', function () {
    $('#myImg').tooltip('hide')
});
```

See my fiddle here - note that I removed one of the areas because of the uncertainty as to whether the coordinates are correct. It should work fine regardless of how many areas you use, though - the only important thing it's getting from them is their title.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheldon_griffin/bfY56/1/

*<sub>Bootstrap is calling getBoundingClientRect() on the area element, and it is returning 0 for all properties. Possibly correct, possibly not (it seems like that either FireFox or Chrome is giving the wrong answer, though), but definitely the wrong answer for this situation.</sub>

Comment: Note that if you're actually using a different image and wanting the tooltips to go over the areas, it seems like you're going to need to look for a tooltip library that lets you specify the location more directly. You said FireFox works for you, but it does appear to put all tooltips at the bottom of the image, not over an individual area.

Comment: The solution you gave makes sense but surprisingly its not working when I hover over the area tag :-/ , I accepted your answer because your aproach is 100% awesome but I am surprised why isn't it working that way :-/

Comment: Try this updated version - http://jsfiddle.net/sheldon_griffin/bfY56/2/ - it doesn't necessarily fix what you're seeing, but I was seeing tooltips flickering and disappearing, which I fixed by calling destroy instead of hide. I also added a few more areas.. it works pretty well in my Chrome and Firefox, anyway. If all else fails, [qTip2](http://qtip2.com/demos), for example, does tooltips over imagemaps.

Comment: Thanks alot for this version & its working awesome at my end. Kindly don't forget to mention your updated fiddle in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
coords="0,33,21,54"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4HptX/55/